# How to create a web application framework

Tags: rust, frameworks

I want to attempt creating a framework like Ruby on Rails but for Rust. I know it will take long and it's a lot of work but I figured it would help me better understand the abstractions that are used in frameworks and reasoning behind framework developers' decisions. By building a framework I will also get to learn lots about the framework I'm building. The only projects I've created with Rust is Philip Opperman's Rust OS, a Ray Tracer and a sudoku game using the Piston engine. Can anyone give me some tips/pointers on how to go about this project or where to start? I want to build it specifically for API development.

Comment: I'd start by getting familiarized with the apis in other crates; they will show you how to design things in a rust-like fashion. Also, you'll probably need quite a bit of rust intuition, so that you won't end up fighting the borrow checker as often. Perhaps designing your project in a modular fashion; using traits very often, using various crates, etc. can make its development easier.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. Also got some advice from someone else today who suggested that I build a project and extract from there.

Comment: Checkout romio...

Comment: @MatthieuM., do you have a link? When I Google `romio` the top results are an app to find service providers. EDIT: found it here https://docs.rs/romio/0.3.0-alpha.10/romio/

Comment: Oh, and you might also want to look at the async book: it explains [how to build an Executor](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/02_execution/04_executor.html).